# Getting an error while trying to debug an ASP.NET (WebForms) app that I've migrated

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to migrate an ASP.NET 2.0 app (WebForms) to ASP.NET 3.5.  I've finally fixed a 500.19 IIS 7.5 error I was having.  Now it will run, so long as I don't attempt to debug it.  If I do attempt to debug it I get an error message.  I've searched for help on this error and there's precious little out there.  Here's the text of the error message:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server.  Check for one of the following.
>
> 1. The application you are trying to debug uses a version of the Microsoft .NET Framework that is not supported by the debugger.
> 2. The debugger has made an incorrect assumption about the Microsoft .NET Framework version your application is going to use.
> 3. The Microsoft .NET Framework version specified by you for debugging is incorrect.
>
> Please see the Visual Studio .NET debugger documentation for correctly specifying the Microsoft .NET Framework version your application is going to use for debugging.

Well, as far as I know, I'm using the correct version of the .NET Framework (3.5) for this app.  Although I am not as familiar with IIS 7.5 on Windows 7.

Comment: You would have to attach to the IIS worker process via the Debug->Attach to Process menu in VS.  Is that what you're doing or are you just pressing F5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that I had to get into IIS and change the application pool that my upgraded ASP.NET app was using.  It had been assigned to an application pool that's associated with .NET 4.0.  I changed it to one related to .NET Framework 2.0.